# How to wait in selenium for long time effectively

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am automating once test case and steps are :

1. Go to website
2. Go to Report Page
3. Fill information form to request report
4. Download report once it display on page

Here main thing is after filling form to request report , Report available to download in same page after 25 to 30 minutes of request.

So is there any better way to wait for 30 minutes until here my report available to download?

After submit request , I am thinking to put logic like :

```
do{

   //click somewhere on page constantly where nothing happens but just to be active

}while(reportelement.size!=1);
```

And as soon as I get report size > 0 , I will click on download link.

I know that selenium provides explicit wait but bit confuse about how that can be implemented here.

I am not looking for whole scenario code, just a good logic would help me a lot to automate this wait stuff.

Comment: I think wasting 30 mins in a code is itself bad test. Shouldn't you be splitting the test in 2, one to generated and one to check the report after 30 mins or so?

Comment: @Tarun- Actually report generate is not in my control. All I can is request for report and check till next 30 minutes if report available to download or not.

Comment: What I meant is you run two test, one which generates the report and 2nd which is executed lets say 30 mins later and comes back and checks if the report is available on the same page?

Comment: I understood but in that case I will have to fire second test case manually after 30 minutes. as we are not using any CI for now to schedule test cases.

Comment: Understood, posted an answer with the current understanding of the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you can't split the test I would suggest to keep it simple like below

```
int timeTaken = 0;
int TIMEOUT = 30 * 60;

do {
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    timeTaken = timeTaken + 1;
    reportelement = driver.findElements(...);
} while (timeTaken < TIMEOUT && reportelement.size != 1)
```

`FluentWait` is good to not waste time when the element is available and avoid hard coded waits. Since here we are anyways expecting a 30 min kind of delay, so and extra min wasted to identify the element won't matter. But the code is quite simplified for the use case.

Since you are doing `findElements`, you don't need to take any other actions on the page as such, the connection will still be active with the driver

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. very logical answer.

Comment: Hi. one question here. what if I want to give some message in case if element does not available after within 30 minutes? I want to exit from while and give some message.

Comment: You can check the `reportelement.size` outside the loop. If it is still `0` then the element was not found within the timeout

Comment: So you mean it will exit from do..while anyhow after 30 minutes?

Comment: Yes that what TIMEOUT defines

Comment: I see but I thought as it is && condition it wont. Thanks. I understood now.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the cleanest way to do this using the `FluentWait` approach would be a custom [Sleeper](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Sleeper.html).  This can do what you like between the checks.

`Sleeper` is one of the parameters on the full constructor to `WebDriverWait`, e.g. :

```
    Sleeper sleeper = duration -> {
        // Click somewhere
        Sleeper.SYSTEM_SLEEPER.sleep(duration);
    };

    long longTimeout = 1800_000;
    FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,
            new SystemClock(), sleeper, longTimeout,
            WebDriverWait.DEFAULT_SLEEP_TIMEOUT)
                    .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class);

    By by = By.id(id); // (As appropriate)

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBe(by, 1));
```

- the other constructor parameters there are just the normal defaults.  Probably a longer `sleepTimeOut` would make sense here too.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for answer. I will try and update you here.