# Test scripts using Selenium and C# for asynchronous wait of 26 minutes

Tags: c#, selenium

How to write test scripts using Selenium and C# for asynchronous wait of 26 minutes? We have to wait for 26 to 30 minutes in our test scripts after clicking one of the buttons. We have a processing bar in between and able to see other buttons after 26 minutes.

Comment: What happens if one day it takes longer than 26 minutes?

Comment: This is in java but I am sure logic will help you [Wait for long time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50076540/how-to-wait-in-selenium-for-long-time-effectively)